# RDF databases on Android

Tags: android, database, rdf, semantic-web, triplestore

I'm working on a project on mobile RDF databases for Android. Therefore I'm looking for open source databases to include in my Android project. However, it's difficult for me to find mobile versions of existing RDF databases.

What I've found so far:

- Jena TDB database
- [Oracle Berkeley database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)

Unfortunately I haven't found mobile versions of Sesame, Virtuoso, AllegroGraph, etc.

Does anyone know some other RDF databases for Android?

Comment: See also: http://code.google.com/p/androjena/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Android developer, so perhaps I'm overlooking something, but Sesame comes as a [collection of maven modules](https://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases/org/openrdf/sesame/), each a separate Java jar file. You can pick and choose the jar files you need and as far as I'm aware, you should be able to use them on Android straightaway. I don't think there's any need for a separate "mobile version", is there?

Comment: I've been informed that there are some issues with using Sesame on Android, in particular because it relies on the Java Service Provider Interface (SPI), which apparently isn't well-supported in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a look to [Triple Place](https://github.com/white-gecko/TriplePlace).

> a light weight and flexible Triple Store for Android. It uses a
>   indexing structure similar to the one in Hexastore. TriplePlace uses
>   TokyoCabinet as persistent storage system.

You can find a brief presentation of its features [here](http://skill.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/SKIL2011_Arndt.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQLite to store RDF data and make queries for the triples, but SPARQL couldn't be done. Here is a good reference:

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~melnik/rdf/db.html

I would also take a look at [4store](http://4store.org/).

Comment: That link is extraordinarily out of date, and I'm not sure running 4Store on a phone is an appropriate design choice.